# Creating custom projection using provided Helmert Parameters and ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, coordinate-system

I am using ArcMap 10.5.1.

I need to transform coordinates in ArcMap from the a PCS based on Cape Lo23 to PCS Hartebeesthoek Lo23 and vice versa on a fairly regular basis.

I am based in South Africa and the firm I'm working for makes use of the Cape Lo23-based system, while the rest of the world around me has moved on to the WGS based Hartebeesthoek datum.

Unfortunately just doing the conversion from Cape to Hartebeesthoek does not do the trick. I've been provided with conversion parameters in a file as seen below:

```
Helmert transformation
Control file with common points:
LO23-WG23.txt
System: Hartebeesthoek Lo23
T10                   -2268.780     3082710.040        1348.500
T15                   -8331.570     3062024.210        1286.000
T55                    2709.900     3066723.330        1200.100
T56                    1764.640     3074419.150        1242.800
T88                    5958.520     3078289.860        1191.200
T91                    5833.070     3057433.050        1154.900
T92                   13139.630     3070191.270        1191.500
T108                  -8438.950     3081274.270        1258.100
T138                  -1194.350     3057095.420        1176.600
System: Local Cape based Lo23
T10                   -2323.674     3082426.023        1348.500
T15                   -8386.703     3061740.192        1286.000
T55                    2654.917     3066439.162        1200.100
T56                    1709.668     3074135.043        1242.800
T88                    5903.646     3078005.644        1191.200
T91                    5777.992     3057148.793        1154.900
T92                   13084.588     3069906.924        1191.500
T108                  -8494.080     3080990.149        1258.100
T138                  -1249.450     3056811.216        1176.600
Conversion from: WG23   to: LO23

Transformation parameters:
Eo =      -79.673546298998
No =      -296.804231105685
A =       1.00000412077644
B =       -8.0281154962317E-06
Rotation: -4.5997523991264E-04
Scale:    1.00000412080866
Transformed control points:
Pnt                     E               N           dE         dN
T10                   -2323.715     3082425.957     0.0405     0.0659
T15                   -8386.696     3061740.091    -0.0074     0.1014
T55                    2654.858     3066439.141     0.0594     0.0207
T56                    1709.656     3074135.001     0.0125     0.0424
T88                    5903.584     3078005.693     0.0621    -0.0489
T91                    5777.966     3057148.798     0.0261    -0.0049
T92                   13084.658     3069907.012    -0.0704    -0.0879
T108                  -8493.921     3080990.231    -0.1585    -0.0818
T138                  -1249.486     3056811.223     0.0358    -0.0070
```

Here are the isolated parameters:

```
Transformation parameters:
Eo =      -79.673546298998
No =      -296.804231105685
A =       1.00000412077644
B =       -8.0281154962317E-06
Rotation: -4.5997523991264E-04
Scale:    1.00000412080866
```

The way I am thinking of approaching this problem is by creating a custom transformation, but I am not sure at all which Method to choose (Geocentric, Coordinate Frame, Position Vector, etc.) and how these parameters tie into the chosen method.

Comment: Are you setting the existing Cape to Hartebeesthoek94 transformation? And it's not adequate? Esri doesn't support PCS-PCS transformations which is what you have.

Comment: Unfortunately using Cape to HTB transformation doesn't give me the result I'm looking to achieve, the points do not align and are offset by greater than 40 meters.

Perhaps I should transform the HTB coordinates to WGS 1984 Lat Long and try to work from there?